# Install Angular Unsupported Engine, OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am reinstalling my MacBook. And I receive the following message when I install (`npm install -g @angular/cli`) angular. Any idea why? I suspect the nom version but I comes along with node...

```
Developments npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/cli@11.1.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1101.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@11.1.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics@11.1.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/angular@11.1.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/update@0.1101.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

    added 241 packages, and audited 242 packages in 12s
    
    20 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    
    found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Update - 25th Feb 2021

npm `7.5.6` or greater now works with `angular-cli` versions `9.1.15`, `10.2.3`, `11.2.2`, `12.0.0-next.2` or greater *(within each major version)* as per  *[this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957#issuecomment-786177315)* from the Angular team

### Original Message - 7th Feb 2021

As of writing npm 7 is not fully supported by `angular-cli` as per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957#issuecomment-773569798)

I also get the same warnings on Windows with `current: { node: 'v15.4.0', npm: '7.5.2' }`

Angular CLI returns a warning when I run `ng new` with npm 7 and offers a workaround

```
npm version 7.5.2 detected.
The Angular CLI currently requires npm version 6.

Please install a compatible version to proceed (`npm install --global npm@6`).
```

[npm 7 was made generally available very recently on 2nd Feb 2021](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/)

This an ongoing issue and the npm team have recently [added a comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957#issuecomment-774400406) in response to the Angular team to the aforementioned GitHub issue.

Comment: So, should I downgrade the version of Node/Npm?

Comment: Don't think there is a need to downgrade node.

If you need a workaround to use `ng` right now then you can follow the error message instructions and try downgrading npm to version 6 `npm install --global npm@6`.

But you might want to subscribe to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957) to see if there are any npm 7 compatible workarounds or fixes in the future.

Comment: Update: npm 7.5.6 should work with `angular-cli` in an upcoming release.

The angular team has made a change to *"remove npm 7 incompatibility notification"* in this [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/20132) which as of writing has been merged to `master` but not yet released.

I will edit and update my answer once the new version of `angular-cli` has been released.

Comment: downgrade npm works for me . Use below command : npm install --global npm@6.14.16

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. it's working with:

Upgrade the npm version

```
npm install -g npm@7.22.0
```

check the current version

Comment: I think the last version minor version of npm is [v7.24.2](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases)

Comment: yes I know, check the date that I posted it.
the problem forced me to specify the update manually

Comment: the comment is for other people coming to this answer

Comment: Worked for me.
Had following version error:


npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1202.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.14.2', npm: '8.5.5' }

Answer (score 5):

This issue is because the npm version

npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', **npm: '^6.11.0'**, yarn: '>= 1.13.0' }

- node: '>= 10.13.0' angular cli requires a version greater or equal to
  10.13.0
- npm: '^6.11.0' here the caret (^) means "Compatible with version"
  6.11 and you have a version 7.5.2

[check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) to learn more about npm symbols like ^ or ~

all you have to do is install a compatible version

```
sudo npm i -g npm@6.11.0
```

Comment: As was said above it's best not to use `sudo` as it can result in permission conflicts when doing updates and work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the upgrade to a newer `angular-devkit` fixed the issue.

Now im using: Angular 11.2.6 with npm 7.6.3

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.5",
    ...
```