# NestJS "Warn EBADENGINE unsupported engine @angulardevkit" when trying to install class-validator and class-transformer

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, nestjs

I am working through the course on the NestJS website. I need to install class-validator and class-transformer `npm i class-validator class-transformer`

But when I do I get error:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@12.2.10',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.11.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics@12.2.10',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.11.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics-cli@12.2.10',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.11.0', npm: '8.0.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

I don't understand how to fix this.

NestJS and Angular seem to be aware of this issue as there has been a brief [discussion between the 2 teams on GitHub Memory](https://githubmemory.com/repo/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/1378). Something about the latest version of Angular not supporting npm 8 or higher?

But it seems like the Angular team released a [fix for this in the release on 20th October 2021 - 4 days ago](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1300-rc0-2021-10-13)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04
Node 16.11
npm 8

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Angular Unsupported Engine, OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088443/install-angular-unsupported-engine-osx)

Comment: I'm not sure so `npm install --global npm@7`?

Comment: Or `npm install --global npm@7.5.6`. I'm new to node, will doing this downgrade my npm from 8 to 7.5.6?

Answer (score 9):

**Updated 18.11.2021:**

NestJS has updated the dependencies (in particular `@nestjs/cli@8.1.5`),
so now you can update your project dependencies (just run `npm update`) and switch back to using npm@8 (just run `npm install -g npm@8`).

**Original answer:**

Yes, what you should do today — is downgrade npm to version 7.
To do this, just run `npm install -g npm@7`.

Npm v8 support has already been added to angular (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#12211-2021-10-20), but we are still waiting for NestJS to update the dependencies. As soon as that happens, you should be able to switch back to npm v8 by running `npm i -g npm@8`.